# NSPredicate format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate

I want to filter `NSArray` with using `NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:` method. I have some variable, which I want to use several times in this format. I do not want to write it several times. Here is an example:

```
NSString *someText = @"some text";
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:
          @"(field1 CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) OR (field2 CONTAINS[cd] %1$@)", someText];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
// prints : (field1 CONTAINS[cd] some text) OR (field2 CONTAINS[cd] some text)
```

So it works with `NSString stringWithFormat:`

Can someone explain why **it doesn't work** with `NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:` and how to fix it?

```
[someArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
         @"(field1 CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) OR (field2 CONTAINS[cd] %1$@)", 
     someText]];
```

I receive this exception:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string `"(field1 CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) OR (field2 CONTAINS[cd] %1$@)"'`

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried a predicate with block yet?

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote my code to use predicateWithBlock, it works great. Still wandering why format doesn't work.

Comment: $ in predicateWithFormat is used for something else, read this for more informations.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSPredicate` parser does not accept positional specifiers perhaps due to the `$` sign used to declare variables. And by the way, using variables could be a solution to your question.

```
NSString *someText = @"some text";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
         @"(field1 CONTAINS[cd] $someText) OR (field2 CONTAINS[cd] $someText)"]];
NSDictionary *varSub = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:someText forKey:@"someText"];
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:varSub];
```

Although it's probably not much shorter than retyping the variable name...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

You're passing a literal string as an argument to `-predicateWithFormat:` rather than the result of

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(field1 CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) OR (field2 CONTAINS[cd] %1$@)", someText];
```

ORIGINAL

Your `-stringWithFormat:` call provides a formatting string that has 2 placeholders but you only provide one value.

Comment: Correct, what is why %1$@ is used. So it works without any problems